# Consuming restful with angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using the $resource service to consume. Below is my code. When I open the file in Chrome no values appear except for the curly braces with the expressions inside. The rest service is fine and I can invoke it directly by typing the url. Can some one please help me. I am a little new to angular.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

        app.factory("Employee", function($resource) {
          return $resource("http://localhost:8080/RestApp/doj/webservice/json/employee/:empId");
        });

        app.controller("EmpController", function($scope, Employee) {
            Employee.get({ empId: 22222 }, function(data) {
                $scope.employee = data;
              });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="EmpController">
            <p>The address is {{employee.address}}</p>
            <p>The employee id {{employee.employeeId}}</p>

        <p>The employee name {{employee.employeeId}}</p>
            <p>The job is {{employee.jobType}}</p>enter code here
            <p>The salary is {{employee.salary}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>`
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't specify the name of your app in `ng-app` directive - it probably should be `myApp` according to your code. Secondly, the version of AngularJS you're using is way too old and incompatible with the version of angular-resource. Try using 1.3.15 and it will resolve this issue.